SPFX Webpart with Azure Functions unable to retrieve client secret in Teams App
We developed an SPFX webpart that uses Azure Functions with graph api and we want to transition it to a Teams Personal Tab App. Everything works in the SharePoint context, but in the teams web client the azure functions are not called, due to the app not retrieving the client secret properly.
All the necessary API Permissions are granted. In the package-solution file of the application the scope of our App Registration is correctly set under the "webApiPermissionRequests" and granted on the SharePoint Admin Center. From there we used the Add To Teams option to add our webpart to teams, but when entering on the teams web client the webpart appears, but the azure functions are not called, throwing "403: Unable to retrieve client secret" error , with the resource being our scope from 'Expose an API' and the client ID being the 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal'.
This is the URL that fails :
https://{mytenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysite}/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Internal.ClientSideComponent.Token.AcquireOBOToken?resource={GUID of my AAD app registration}&clientId={GUID of SharePoint Online Client Extensibility AAD app registration}
Also tried by writing the manifest.json manually and upload the ZIP package to teams, same error.
The functions are called by using an AadHttpClient and the context as WebPartContext from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base'.
It's the first time working with this and found no working solutions. If someone had a similar issue in the past, I would really appreciate some help.

Could you please refer these issues once https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8213,   https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7780.
